# worksheet_change run time error

Tags: excel, pivot-table, selectionchanged, vba

The code below works for a pivot table data range on a  sheet that when "SelectionChange" is activated (every click) it updates all "PivotTable3"'s on each worksheet. It usually works unless I edit it and retry

QUESTION: how to use "Worksheet_Change" for this? I always get a run time error and can't figure out the syntax

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Call PivRefresh
Next
End Sub


Sub PivRefresh()
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotCache.refresh
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You're referencing the same sheet each time - you need something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotCache.Refresh
    Next
End Sub
```

No need for the `PivRefresh()` sub